# strftime(('%Y-%m',tr_date) not working in SQlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

Hello friends i wnat to display data as per month wise in my applicaiton my code as below

```
public class IncomeActivity extends ListActivity {

Button mbutoonmonth;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_income);
    DatabaseConnectionAPI mDatabaseConnectionAPI=new DatabaseConnectionAPI(getApplicationContext());
mTextViewMonth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String StartDate="";


            int mYear = 0;
            int mMonth;
            int mDay;
            int dayOFWeek = 0;
            String mondayDate="";
            Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);

            mCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);

            mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            if (mMonth==10|mMonth==11|mMonth==12) {
                 StartDate=String.valueOf(mYear)+"-"+String.valueOf(mMonth);
                System.out.println("Start DAte "+StartDate);
            }
            else {
                 StartDate=String.valueOf(mYear)+"-0"+String.valueOf(mMonth);
                System.out.println("Start DAte "+StartDate);
            }

            mArrayListTransactions=mDatabaseConnectionAPI.getIncomeMonthData(mStringTrMode,StartDate);
            mCustomListviewAdapter=new CustomListviewAdapter(IncomeActivity.this, mArrayListTransactions);
            mListView.setAdapter(mCustomListviewAdapter);
        }
    });
   }
}
```

**DatabaseConnectionAPI.java**

```
 public ArrayList<ParsesrTransaction> getIncomeMonthData(String mode ,String date) {

    ArrayList<ParsesrTransaction> mGetCategoryList = new ArrayList<ParsesrTransaction>();
    try {
        String sqlQuery = "select tr_date  from Transaction_Master where strftime('%Y-%m', tr_date) = "+ "'"+date+"'" ;
        Cursor mCursorCategory = Query(sqlQuery);
        if (mCursorCategory != null) {
            mCursorCategory.moveToFirst();
            while (!mCursorCategory.isAfterLast()) {

                ParsesrTransaction mParserCategory = new ParsesrTransaction();
                mParserCategory
                .setCatID(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("cat_id")));
                mParserCategory
                .setCatName(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("cat_name")));
                mParserCategory
                .setTrDate(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("tr_date")));
                mParserCategory
                .setTrDetail(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("tr_detail")));
                mParserCategory
                .setTrMode(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("tr_mode")));
                mParserCategory
                .setTrPrice(mCursorCategory.getString(mCursorCategory
                        .getColumnIndex("tr_price")));
                mGetCategoryList.add(mParserCategory);
                mCursorCategory.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        mCursorCategory.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mGetCategoryList;
}
```

when i run abouve code it give me message like

```
01-29 14:27:11.890: E/CursorWindow(9965): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 3, numColumns = 1
01-29 14:27:11.890: W/System.err(9965): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
01-29 14:27:11.890: W/System.err(9965):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
01-29 14:27:11.900: W/System.err(9965):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
01-29 14:27:11.900: W/System.err(9965):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
01-29 14:27:11.900: W/System.err(9965):     at pkg.android.rootways.rootmoney.helper.DatabaseConnectionAPI.getIncomeMonthData(DatabaseConnectionAPI.java:646)
01-29 14:27:11.900: W/System.err(9965):     at pkg.android.rootways.rootmoney.IncomeActivity$9.onClick(IncomeActivity.java:268)
```

Any idea how can i solve it ?

Comment: select tr_date  from Transaction_Master where  tr_date = "+ "'"+strftime('%Y-%m',date)+"'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only projecting `tr_date` column to the cursor but are trying to access five other columns as well. `getColumnIndex()` returns -1 for columns not present in the cursor.

Possibly a `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT tr_date` will work.